# Why smaller alloc doesn't change malloc_info but larger ones does

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc

I was playing around with `malloc_info` today and I discovered some very strange behaviors. The `malloc_info` size doesn't grow linearly with the size of malloc I am calling. It jumps around with different parameters to malloc and there are certain magic numbers that just keeps showing up. I was guessing this might be some kind of optimization by c to allocate chunk by chunk without actually using all of them.

Some interesting magic numbers

`<aspace type="total" size="135168"/>` happens for most of malloc calls that don't ask for a huge memory. Like `malloc(1500)`

`<system type="current" size="270336"/>` happens for slightly larger ones. Like `malloc(1500` called 100 times in a loop.

But the interesting thing is, `malloc(1000)` called 100 times in a loop gives me the magic number `135168` again. So it seems to be some arbitrary cut off between 1000 and 1500 called 100 times in a loop.

Can anyone shine some light on this strange behavior? I am doing a task of replacing old `mallinfo` with 64 bit compatible function

Comment: `malloc` *may* allocate space larger than requested depending on the algorithm used.

Comment: (135168 B is 132 KiB and 270336 B is 264 KiB.)

Comment: @ikegami it looks pretty interesting almost feels like page by page. But page is wayy smaller than this. If this is an optimization, why is malloc_info not abstracting away this

Comment: Since `malloc_info` is a GNU extension, you might want to read [the glibc manual's chapter on memory management](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Memory.html#Memory).  You might also look around for a definition of what `malloc_info`'s output means, as I suspect your surprise arises in part from misinterpreting it.

Comment: Isn't easier instead of asking seeing the malloc source for your system